# Twilio I'm sending a bulk SMS to customers in US, how to reduce 30003 errors Unreachable destination handset?

Tags: twilio, sms, twilio-twiml

For about 5 of the past 8 days I've sent a bulk sms to about 100 customers a day using Twilio. Each day I send to a new group of customers, so a particular customer is only receiving one text message in total.

I am using a long phone number to send the text messages. The first couple days I only got between 3 and 6 30003 errors - Unreachable destination handset. Yesterday I got 11 30003 errors and today I got 18 30003 errors.

This escalation in 30003 errors is concerning, is there anything that I can do to prevent this. Is my Twilio number being blocked by the carriers now?

I've already seen the following but would like insight from a Twilio Evangelist:

Messages sent from long codes
Repeated Error 30003 results on undelivered messages sent from long codes (regular phone numbers) could be due to carrier filtering.
The rules for carrier filtering vary throughout the industry, making it difficult at times to pin down exactly why a message is being filtered out. For more details including potential workarounds, please see this Help Center article "How Does Carrier Filtering Work?"

https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223181848-How-Does-Carrier-Filtering-Work-

Answer (score 1):

Best (but costly) solution is to use short codes:
https://www.twilio.com/docs/glossary/what-is-a-short-code

If that solution is too costly try to spread out the frequency of the texts. Try multiple numbers / multiple accounts. Use url shorteners on urls in the body of the text. Add opt out options. None of the above - other than short codes - is going to work over the long run in my experience.